# How do you properly align radio buttons in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button, radio-group

I have three radio groups each with two button inside of them. As you can see from this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rryqI.jpg [1] ,the buttons are all lined up nicely in android studio. However, when I run the app in the VM I end up with this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDw7n.jpg [2].

Any ideas why this is occurring? Thanks in advance for any help.

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="onerepmax.reversepyramid.RPworkout">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/workoutButton"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:width="175dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/warmupButton"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:width="175dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/liftText"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="xxx lbs"
        android:id="@+id/weightText1"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/repText1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/repText1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/repText1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="XX reps"
        android:id="@+id/repText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/liftText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/liftText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/liftText"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="xxx lbs"
        android:id="@+id/weightText2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/weightText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weightText3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/weightText3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="XX reps"
        android:id="@+id/repText2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/repText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/repText1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/repText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="xxx lbs"
        android:id="@+id/weightText3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/weightText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weightText1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/weightText1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="XX reps"
        android:id="@+id/repText3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/repText1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/repText1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/repText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nextButton"
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/weightText3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/liftText"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:checked="false"
            android:buttonTint="#2ebb39"
            android:layout_marginTop="59dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
            android:buttonTint="#d32323"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weightText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weightText3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:checked="false"
            android:buttonTint="#2ebb39"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="45dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:buttonTint="#d32323"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_below="@+id/repText2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nextButton">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
            android:checked="false"
            android:buttonTint="#2ebb39"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="29dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:buttonTint="#d32323"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share the full xml for this layout, showing radio group without the elements they actually align to is not very helpful

Comment: OK, edited to include full xml file.

Comment: for starters your not using the radio groups correctly, you can vastly improve your layout using the RadioButton provided text element

Comment: I can't imagine how that would even work. How would you get the UI that I have right now, while using the provided text element? Furthermore, I don't think that not having text means that I'm using them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your alignment issue, also there is no need to have to label text views, instead do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="onerepmax.reversepyramid.RPworkout">

    <!-- Even spaced buttons above -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_wrapper"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Workout"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Warmup"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Centered Text -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/liftText"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_wrapper"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <!-- Centered Radio Group with Label 1 -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/set_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/liftText"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?listPreferredItemHeight">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_lbs_1"
            android:text="xxx lbs xx reps"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_lbs_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:buttonTint="#2ebb39"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:buttonTint="#d32323"/>

        </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Centered Radio Group with Label 2 -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/set_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/set_1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?listPreferredItemHeight">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_lbs_2"
            android:text="xxx lbs xx reps"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_lbs_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup2">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonPassTwo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:buttonTint="#2ebb39"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonFailTwo"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:buttonTint="#d32323"/>

        </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Centered Radio Group with Label 3 -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/set_3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/set_2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?listPreferredItemHeight">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_lbs_3"
            android:text="xxx lbs xx reps"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_lbs_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup3">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonPassThree"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:buttonTint="#2ebb39"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButtonFailThree"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:buttonTint="#d32323"/>

        </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Workout"
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And when you want to set something like "200 lbs 10 reps" for the TextView with `txt_lbs_1`

do:

```
 TextView mTextViewLbs1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_lbs_1);
 mTextViewLbs1.setText(String.format("%1$d lbs %2$d reps", 200, 3));
```

This yields:

[image: View with aligned RadioGroups and single label]

Good luck and hope this points you in a better direction.

Happy Coding!

Comment: The problem is that that doesn't make sense as far as the app is concerned. The radio buttons in this case are Pass / Fail buttons. It wouldn't make sense to have the weight next to the pass button and the reps next to the fail button.

Comment: Ahh @crseat I see I miss interpreted there purpose will give an update in a few

Comment: @crseat see updated answer above, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes this fixed it. I actually do need two text views because of how the program works, but even after I added the other text views back in your code still worked much better than mine. I think it had to do with how poorly I shaped the radio groups. Thanks